# Adding target blank to hyperlink

Tags: php

i am having problem in adding the target=_blank to links. My link is coming in a variable from the database.

```
buy it:<?php echo $abc ?>
```

If i use firebud then it looks like:

```
 buy it:<a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007DB7O2Q" rel="nofollow noreferrer"> Amazon </a>
```

please let me know how will i add target=_blank to this link.

Comment: $abc contains the link, edit that

Comment: Try `target="_blank"` instead.

Comment: What is your $abc string? Also your starting bracket is not a php <?php so this would not work at all

Comment: @Dagon can you please let me know how to edit this. i do not want to use databse. i want to use something like javascript.

Comment: @Dagon $abc is having link <a hfref............>amazon</a>.

Comment: yessss but $abc is defined somewhere, somehow, that's where the *target blank* should be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your links are in the database you could do something like str_replace("<a ", "<a target='_blank' ", $var):

Comment: Didn't work for me, but `preg_replace('/(<a href="[^"]+")>/is','\\1 target="_blank">',$var);` did

Answer (score 2):

You can add the tag `base` to the head of your document, which will change the target of all your links.

```
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

Specifying a different target on an anchor tag will override this default option which is good for if you have other links that you don't want the target to be blank.

Comment: The best solution. I say. But what if he doesn't wana add it to other links??

Comment: Edited my answer to include this scenario.

Comment: Well all you know, hes too lazy to add it to all links. I was just saying..... I agreed and +1d long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's really better if you do this kind of job on the client side.

Use javascript

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].target="_blank";
```